# How to use function added with class decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have created a class decorator that all it does is add a function to the prototype of a class

```
export function myDecorator(target: any): any {
'use strict';
var original = target;

function construct(constructor, args) {
    var c: any = function () {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    };
    c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new c();
}

var f: any = function (...args) {
    return construct(original, args);
};

f.prototype = original.prototype;

f.prototype.decoratedFunction = function() {
    // decorated function body
};

return f;}
```

But.. when I decorate a class the decorated function cannot be resolved and thus it won't compile.

```
 @myDecorator
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        this.decoratedFunction();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Or is there no workaround at this point?

Comment: this["decoratedFunction"](); otherwise you should declare it

Comment: Thanks. that will do for now

Answer (score 0):

The ways you can use this function are:

1) Declare it in the class:

```
@myDecorator
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.decoratedFunction();
    }
    decoratedFunction: () => void;
}
```

2) Use square brackets:

```
this["decoratedFunction"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have the function added by the decorator typed and "usable" in typescript. The reason for this is that the function is only ever added at run time (in the javascript not the typescript code).

As has ben pointed out already the only way to get this to work is to add a stub or to use the bracket notation. This seems to be a bad use of decorators, they should be used to add functionality that is not explicitly needed by a class. Like injection, validation or debug logging for example.

What you want to do is essential to the how the class works. If you remove the decorator the class will throw an error because the method added is called in the class, this in my mind should not be the case.

A simple base class should solve the problem for you, nice and tidy:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
    protected decoratedFunction() {
        // do some magic.. 
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    constructor() {
        this.decoratedFunction();
    }
}
```

Other solutions might be to use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...
}

class DecoratedClass extends SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.decoratedFunction();
    }
    private decoratedFunction() {
        // Do some magic....
    }
}
```

Or to use composition ([composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) to add the functionality:

```
class ClassWithMagic {
    public decoratedFunction() {
        // Do some magic...
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    private compositionInstance = new ClassWithMagic();
    constructor() {
        this.compositionInstance.decoratedFunction();
    }
}
```

Hope this helped. A decorator simply does not seem to be the right solution to your problem, oop has tones of other ways to solve the same problem however.